# Grails tool suite (GGTS) Package explorer changed

Tags: grails, ggts

I did something I didnt noticed and it changed to folder icon unlike before where controller view and domain class has specific icon

[image]

my biggest concern though is that create new gsp has disappeared

[image]

anyone can teach me how to change GGTS package explorer to its default settings?

edit:
additional info to make my question clearer

I want my package explorer to be back to default just like this [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in Package Explorer.

Change the settings of View in GGTS to Project Explorer.Then you should be able to find Create View etc options

*Select the Menu options*

**Window -> Show View -> Project Explorer**